# Plugin or Theme causes Fatal Wordpress Error

Tags: wordpress

I am encountering an annoying problem with my Wordpress website.
I changed the theme, and one of my plugin doesn't seem to be working properly.
Here is the page that use the plugin: https://www.soccerclub.be/reser-test

The error message is:
`Fatal error: Cannot declare class wp_booking_calendar_public_setting, because the name is already in use in /home/soccercl/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-booking-calendar/public/class/settings.class.php on line 3`

I don't really understand what it means. If someone has a guess on how to solve this problem this would save my life as I just spend a lot of time working on the new theme and really need this specific plugin to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Romain and welcome to StackOverflow. It looks that the new theme that you have activated did conflict with your plugin "wp-booking-calendar" this usually happens when 2 plugins or a plugin and a theme use the name for 2 functions or class. IN your case its a class name.

The error says "Cannot declare class wp_booking_calendar_public_setting," this means that on that page something else is using the same class name "wp_booking_calendar_public_setting" usually plugin can not get such conflict because they are using their custom names.

I can help you if you shared with me the theme full name, I will dig in its code and get he issue.

Comment: Hello Mohamed,

Thank you for your swift answer, this is awesome!
The theme is "Semplice" from www.semplice.com
I am pretty sure there is nothing using this class on the theme code as it is supposed to be a portfolio theme and has nothing to do with bookings.

This might be useful for you : the plugin is embedded on this specific page by using a shortcode.

Comment: I would update all the plugins and themes. Also, did you add any custom code to the theme? or anywhere else?

Comment: I did not, I only used the builder.

Comment: Actually, someone else did the first the first version of the website so he might have done something to change the appearance of the booking calendar plugin... I can't really say :/

Comment: EDIT : There are styles option on the plugin so I don't think he had to touch the code

Comment: @RomainDePaepe I would be much of help if we dig in this together, my email is "thegalacticstudio@gmail.com", I will be able to help this way, and after we can post the solution back to this question.